# Habilitar/Deshabilitar textoBox cuando se selecciona determinado elemento del combobox wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, silverlight

Tengo una aplicación que usa WPF usando MVVM con un ComboBox. Cuando se selecciona determinado valor debe deshabilitarse un textbox el XAMl lo tengo así:
**este es el textbox que se requiere habilitar**

```
          <TextBox Name="TCRM" Grid.Row="11" Grid.Column="1"
               Width="100" Height="18" 
               HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
               VerticalAlignment="Center" 
               helpers:TextFilterService.TextBoxFilter="Money" 
               FlowDirection="RightToLeft" MaxLength="4" 
               Margin="10,2,0,1" IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=cbAgregarManual, Path=IsChecked}"
               Text="{Binding Path=Concepto.TCRM, ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors=True, ValidatesOnExceptions=True, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

El combobox que determina si habilita o deshabilita:

```
        <ComboBox Name="ComboTipoPpa" Grid.Row="10" Grid.Column="1"
                  Height="26" Width="177" 
                  HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                  Margin="10,1,0,1"
                  IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=cbAgregarManual, Path=IsChecked}" 
                   ItemsSource="{Binding Path=TipoPpaTos, ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors=False}" 
                  SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedTipoPpaTO, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnValidationError=True}" DisplayMemberPath="Nombre"
                  SelectedValuePath="ValoresPPA"/>
```

si selecciona STR o TR (Tasa representativa) debe dispararse la habilitación del control. ESTA ES LA PARTE QUE no encuentro realizar, en MVVM.

Algo como si en el combobox se selecciona TR se habilita el TextBox Name="TCRM" de otra forma no se habilita

Comment: Pensaste en crear otra propiedad booleana en el ViewModel? Podes hacerle un Getter, donde valides la condición del ComboBox, y la bindeas a IsEnabled del TextBox

Comment: Esa es la respuesta @JuanSalvadorPortugal

Comment: Tienes muchas maneras, con un boolean en el ViewModel, o sin el boolean pero con un Converter que tome el valor seleccionado y que compruebe si debe o no deshabilitarse el control.. yo creo que un Converter sería mejor, el bool es una solución fácil, pero a mi juicio el Converter lo hace más ordenado.

Comment: hola @JuanSalvadorPortugal no conozco bien mvvm estoy con este proyecto realizando una modificación, lo que se me ocurrio fue en el evento SelectionChange del combobox Validar si es TR y habilitarlo, pero creo que eso rompe con el patron MVVM?

Comment: @Leodev me gustaria que escribieras un codigo de ejemplo

Comment: No hay problema.. dame un momento...

Comment: @ger ahí te deje un ejemplo sencillo de lo que propongo, no es la solución más elegante, pero es válida sin romper el patrón mvvm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como dice Leodev en los comentarios, hay varias maneras de solucionar este problema, una de las más sencillas, es el uso de un booleano.

Para explicartelo, voy a usar un ejemplo..

Asumiendo que tenemos el siguiente ViewModel

```
public class TestViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = (sender, e) => { };
protected void OnPropertyChanged() => PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(null));
/// <summary>
/// Lista de ejemplo..
/// </summary>
public IEnumerable<int> Lista { get; } = new List<int>{1,2,3,4,5};
/// <summary>
/// Variable privada elemento seleccionado..
/// </summary>
private int mNumeroSeleccionado;
/// <summary>
/// Exposición del elemento seleccionado
/// </summary>
public int NumeroSeleccionado
{
    get => mNumeroSeleccionado;
    set
    {
        mNumeroSeleccionado = value;
        //Disparo OnPropertyChanged
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }

}
/// <summary>
/// Booleano, que devolverá verdadero, si el número seleccionado es 2 o 4.
/// </summary>
public bool TextBoxActivo => NumeroSeleccionado == 2 || NumeroSeleccionado == 4;
}
```

Luego, en xaml

```
<ComboBox 
            ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Lista}"
            SelectedItem="{Binding Path=NumeroSeleccionado}"></ComboBox>

        <TextBox IsEnabled="{Binding Path=TextBoxActivo}"></TextBox>
```

De esta manera, al cambiar de opción en el ComboBox, se ejecutará el Setter de `NumeroSeleccionado`, por ende, el método `OnPropertyChanged`, que actualizará nuestra vista se ejecutará.

Al ejecutarse, volverá a calcularse la propiedad `TextBoxActivo`, que está bindeada al `IsEnabled` del TextBox.

Por ende, si en el Combo se selecciona, 2 o 4,  el TextBox estará activo, caso contrario, no lo estará.

Comment: me falto comentar que uso Microsoft.Practices.Prism.ViewModel asi que el tuyo resulto mejor Gracias!!

Answer (score 1):

A ver.. hice esto al ojo..
Según mi comentario lo que yo haría es algo así:

Primero:
Crear un `Converter` que reciba el `SelectedItem` (todo el objeto)

```
//using System.Windows.Data;

namespace MyProject.Converters
{
    public class TipoToBoolean : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value != null && value.GetType() == typeof(TipoPpaTo))
            {                    
                //Esto no se bien como lo hiciste pero básicamente es la comprobación que quieres
                if (((TipoPpaTo)value).Nombre.Equals("STR") || ((TipoPpaTo)value).Nombre.Equals("TR"))
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }

            return false;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Luego agregas el `namespace` de tus converters en la ventana y creas una instancia del converter recién hecho:

```
<Window x:Class="MyProject.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:conv="clr-namespace:MyProject.Converters"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <conv:TipoToBoolean x:Key="TipoToBoolean"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <!-- TODA TU VENTANA -->
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Luego al `TextBox` que quieres deshabilitar le controlas el "`IsEnabled`" con el SelectedItem del ViewModel directamente, que creo que es SelectedTipoPpaTO (o con el SelectedItem del ComboBox.. pero si tienes el objeto a mano.. mejor usa el objeto) y ese dato lo envías al converter que te va a devolver un true o un false según el criterio que le quieres definir.. Yo hice algo como esto para el ejemplo:

```
<TextBox Name="TCRM" Grid.Row="11" Grid.Column="1"
Width="100" Height="18" 
HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
VerticalAlignment="Center" 
helpers:TextFilterService.TextBoxFilter="Money" 
FlowDirection="RightToLeft" MaxLength="4" 
Margin="10,2,0,1"
IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=SelectedTipoPpaTO, Converter={StaticResource TipoToBoolean}}"
Text="{Binding Path=Concepto.TCRM, ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors=True, ValidatesOnExceptions=True, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

Y listo.. 
Tal vez lo entendí mal? Bueno.. te dejo el ejemplo, dime si te sirve o lo modifico.

Un saludo

Comment: me parece bien el código, lo modifique pero el que expone JuanSalvadorPortugal es más hmmm simplificado ya que tengo la clase que hereda BaseViewModel y esta a notificationObject esta en Microsoft.Practices.Prism.ViewModel

Comment: Si... como concuerdan todos, hay muchas formas de hacerlo, al final depende de lo que es más cómodo y lo que se adapta más a tu estilo de programación.. tu siéntete libre de hacer las cosas como más te guste, lo importante es que funcione :)